# join query not fetching any data

Tags: php, mysql, join

i am trying to write my first join query which will help me to join two different tables,one is for students and other is for subjects.This is my first join query and it seems it is not working,can anyone point out the mistakes.Php didn't show any error or worning

[image] [image]

```
   try{
     $pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb",'root','');
     $sql="SELECT * FROM students LEFT JOIN subjects WHERE students.courseid=subjects.courseid";
     $conn=$pdo->prepare($sql);
      if($conn->execute()){
        $results=$conn->fetchAll();
        print_r($results);
      }
     }catch(PDOException $e){
         echo $e->getMessage();
     }
```

Comment: If you run your query in MySQL shell you do not get result also?

Comment: Just do var_dump($results); and post the result here

Comment: Where is `courseid` in `subjects` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you table name for students is students and you subjects table is subject then I think it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM students LEFT JOIN subjects on students.courseid=subjects.subjectid
```

because you have a subjectid in your subjects table and not courseid

Comment: join confuses me..hope to get the idea soon ..thanx a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

Replace `WHERE` with `ON` in your query.

```
SELECT * FROM students LEFT JOIN subjects ON students.courseid=subjects.courseid
```

[See Mysql JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: can you explain a bit..it didn't work either though !